# Convert utc date time to local in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, date, time, pipe

I'm getting this date time format

> Sat Nov 18 2023 22:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

```
this.selectedDate = info.date;
```

i want to convert this date time into local date time object but the format will be same

Comment: There is no "local date time object" in ECMAScript, there are just *Date* instances that have a single data property called a time value. It's an offset from the ECMAScript epoch in milliseconds. However, you can use a *Date* to generate a timestamp in various formats and timezones.

Answer (score 1):

You create a `Date` object and then call `toString()`.

```js
let date = new Date("Sat Nov 18 2023 22:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
console.log(date.toString());
```

Since I'm located in Eastern Europe, it converts the date to my timezone and displays it accordingly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Simply you can use the below one line :**

```js
console.log(new Date("Sat Nov 18 2023 22:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)").toString());
```

> Working stackblitz in Angular [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvcc2b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.ts)

[image]

Comment: This answer applies the same idea as my older answer.

Comment: On a edit check after the edit

Answer (score -1):

```
const dateStr = "Sat Nov 18 2023 22:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
const selectedDate = new Date(dateStr);

const localDateTime = selectedDate.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata', // Set your desired timezone here
  weekday: 'short',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric'
});

console.log(localDateTime);
```

Comment: The OP is asking for "local" values, which typically means for the host system, and the same format as the example. Your answer only does the former if an appropriate IANA representative location is used and doesn't do the latter. The simple answer is `new Date(dateStr).toString()`.